# How can I reset the administrator password on my Mac without a Mac OS X installation disc?

Tags: mac, password-recovery

When I bought my Mac mini, I got it without the installation disk and I also didn't get the administrator password. Is there a way to find out in my computer the admin. Password and get a system install disk for it?

Comment: This is really two questions. I would suggest asking them separately: "How can I recover my administrator password?" and "How can I get a system installation disk?"

Comment: In general, it's also helpful to include what version of Mac OS X your computer is running, if you know it.

Answer (score 1):

If the machine doesn't have an [Open Firmware Password](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1352) set, you can reset the password with single-user mode (if it does, you won't be able to access single-user mode without entering the Open Firmware password).

1. Hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> while rebooting the machine. Wait for the machine to boot into single user mode and you will see a `#` prompt.
2. Run `fsck -fy`
3. Run `mount -uw /`
4. Run `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist`
5. Run `dscl . -passwd /Users/username password`, where `username` is the administrator username and `password` is the new password.

([Source](http://www.macyourself.com/2009/08/03/how-to-reset-your-mac-os-x-password-without-an-installer-disc/) for the instructions)