# Restoring new MacBook Pro to factory settings

Tags: macos, passwords, migration

I was given a MacBook Pro at work, but no disks or manuels. I made a huge error by using the migration assistant from my home PC. Now when the MacBook pro comes on, it is asking for a password that I have no idea what it is.

I want to just dump everything I migrated, but when I tried to re-install using `Command R`, it still comes up asking for the password from my home computer.

I really need to dump all of that and start over like I just opened it from work.

Answer (score 3):

Breaking into your account sounds a lot more convenient than formatting and reinstalling, unless you really really wanted to ditch all your data. Here's how to break in instead:

[How can I reset the administrator password on my Mac without a Mac OS X installation disc?](https://superuser.com/questions/299373/how-can-i-reset-the-administrator-password-on-my-mac-without-a-mac-os-x-installa)

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" is that OS X reinstallations don't actually delete your user data. You have to manually erase everything before.

So, assuming you have OS X Lion, reboot into Recovery by holding `⌘R`, and select *Disk Utility* from the options. Erase the Macintosh HD first. Warning: Your data will be completely removed. Then, reinstall OS X using the recovery partition. You'll end up with a fresh system.

For older versions of OS X, there's no Recovery boot, so you need an installation disk. It'd essentially allow you to do the same (i.e. select *Disk Utility* to wipe the Macintosh HD before installation).